# SE Recommendation for Finding S&P 500 Live Data

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am learning some analysis techniques and I use javascript and some other libraries to carry out my analysis. With regards to the analysis techniques, cross validated has been a very helpful community (of which I have been a member for over a year). With regards to the syntax and programming of the techniques, stack overflow has been an invaluable community (of which I have also been a member for almost 2 years). Let me first say these communities have collectively answered almost every question along my journey.

One notable exception is: How to get S&P 500 Live Data. Basically, I want to input a stock sign and have the daily prices feed into my website live or close to live. At which point I will create a javascript application that plots the data graphically. I have posted this question on both Stack Overflow and Cross Validated, but unfortunately each time the question was down-voted extensively and closed as being off-topic. I can see it as being off-topic, but I also think very pluralistically and can just as easily see my side of the argument: it's related to programming, albeit a very niche aspect of it that differs from the majority of questions. I planned to provide a link to the question, but it seems it has been taken down.

I have tried basic search-engine searching, but 95% of the time the results take me to a site that displays the data in graph form already. There is no explanation as to how the site got access to the S&P 500 data. The other problem is that a lot of these sites have tripped my anti-virus software alarms. It seems that search-words with this subject matter are prone to sites with malicious adware/spyware/malware.

**Question:** So that's why I'm consulting the meta here. I would like to see if anyone can recommend a place where my question will be well-received (or at least humored). Which communities should I try? Or is there a clever way to re-phrase my question and try again? Or is my question out of scope for the current communities?

**Note:** Although I'm theoretically open to a non SE solution, I am still partial to a SE community because that way, at least I know it is safe and I wont get a bunch of malware.

Comment: I guess the problem is API questions are a product recommendation. Off topic in most places.

Answer (score 2):

For data recommendations, particularly when you are seeking open data (but often any data, because they hope one day all data will be open) there is the [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You should ask S&P. They will tell you how much it costs, and you can buy a feed licence. This sort of data is rarely provided for free, as it is their business.

I don't know how their pricing model works. You may not find it is cost effective for what you need.